# jQuery autocomplete with lazyLoading

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

iOS API has a beautiful feature which allows a developer to load data lazily in a `UITableView` (which used along with `UISearchBar`, can be used as autocomplete) when a user scrolls down. Can something similar be achieved with jQuery for autocomplete? Such that when user makes a query for say letter "a", the suggestions should be populated with first x number visible results and when the user scrolls down, the view is populated with next x results?

PS : I tried attaching the `scroll` event on the results container of jQuery UI autocomplete, but I couldn't map the amount of scroll to number of results.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery autocomplete has no built in options for doing this, so you'd have to do some plugin hacking to get it working.  You might for example check whether the last item is visible to determine whether to load the next set of data.

Alternatively, you could try a plugin like [Flexbox](http://flexbox.codeplex.com/) which might be more amenable to what you're trying to do.  Flexbox comes with a built in paging feature.

Comment: Great suggestion! Will see if that fits in :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that flexbox pages already available set of results. i.e. it would not allow me to fetch each page's results separately. Is this correct? or I'm missing something?